# Why does Magento (v1.9) uses styles.css from base/default instead of my own theme (Porto)

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, overrides, css, default

I installed Porto theme in Magento, and I can see that the images and overall layout is from this theme. But, it is still taking the `styles.css` form `base/default` and displays firebug error, because it doesn't even exist. Also, the design looks distorted and I can clearly see that CSS is missing. These are some of the settings and directory structure:

- Path to my porto theme in app is: `app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto`
- Path to my porto theme in skin is: `skin/frontend/smartwave/porto`

Things I did and things I tried:

- In `General -> Design` I set the package to smartwave,
- In `General -> Design` I set theme section fields (`skin, layout, default`) to porto.
- I cleared the `cache` as well.

Comment: Is the styles.css on the server in the porto folder? And did you set it in System->Design as Theme?

Comment: The Porto theme doesn't provide the styles.css file at all. I can see it working properly on another server though, another installation with Porto. And on that server, there is no styles.css. And no, it's not set in System -> Design as Theme.

Comment: Which .css is loaded there then?

Comment: No .css is loaded in System -> Design.

Comment: Add it there and choose your theme

Comment: Add what there and where to choose my theme? Sorry, I don't understand you...

Comment: See my screenshot here http://fs5.directupload.net/images/161006/nha5q59y.png

Comment: Do you have CDN or something , if yes then purge at cdn and might be you will see new css will load

Comment: Can you provide the file path for your css file(s) please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you configured magento right to choose your theme and your theme is correct installed than **you inserted a wrong path to your styles.css in your theme´s layout XML**.

*as far as i can see base theme has no styles.css _> that could be the reason for your 404 error*

Comment: Andre, I added that info to the question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a 404 error, I just have a non-existing file, named styles.css being asked for by Magento.

Comment: so your theme has no styles.css at all? 
than maybe in your themes page.xml or local.xml it is defined to use a styles.css. maybe rename your main css file in styles.css _but could be that than your main files is missed than

Comment: Yes, for some reason it doesn't have it.

Comment: if you havent a page.xml in your theme, than it will take the page.xml of your base theme. you can copy the page.xml of base in your theme and remove that line where styles.css is added. 
layout files are in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/

Comment: I have the page.xml in my theme.

Comment: does there is a line with something like _styles.css_ in it? do your frontend has some styles of your theme, i mean does it use any css file?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/76726)

Comment: There is a line with styles.css in it, yes. Somehow there is no styles.css on the other server and somehow there is no error there and the page appears to be fine - it is displayed fine. Contrary to my server, where it is not displayed fine, but distorted. Also on the other server there is no problem with asking for styles.css

Comment: weird seems to be a  server problem or may you not configured your basePath right. hard to say now...

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism sorry for that. like to have some repuation to vote, so i can store questions.

Comment: Andre, since I solved this problem a while ago, but forgot the solution, I will award you the correct answer, although I am not sure what happened, you are correct about styles.css maybe not being in right place can cause this problem.